# In C++, how to extract a substring from a string (or char array) and write it to a string, without getting warnings?

Tags: c++, string, scanf

In C++, I'm reading a file in which the lines are something like

```
     65-82 0.015 0.655
```

where the first is a string (tipically made of numbers separated by a dash or a comma, that then gets processed) and two floating point numbers. I'm currently reading them with the following code, with [line] being a character array:

```
std::string temp_string;
double temp_kb, temp_kt;
int res = sscanf(line, "%s %lf %lf",temp_string,&temp_kb,&temp_kt);
```

this yields a warning:

```
~/TEPInteraction.cpp:1002:76: warning: writing into constant object (argument 3) [-Wformat=]
int res = sscanf(line, "%s %lf %lf",temp_string.c_str(),&temp_kb,&temp_kt);
                                                                        ^
```

which of course makes sense, since c_str() returns a constant pointer. What would be the proper way of doing this without a warning?

Many thanks,
Ferdinando

EDIT:
The value of res was needed to do some controls further down the line, so I'll have to briefly rewrite my code so that it doesn't use it. It's not a big deal but It'll wait until tomorrow. Thanks guys :-) I really appreciate your help.

Comment: `sscanf` is a `C` function. Use `C++`. Take a look at `stringstream` and friends

Comment: You can't use `std::string` directly in the `scanf` family because there are no format specifiers for the `std::string` class.  Characters and C-Style array of strings, but not the C++ `std::string` class.

Answer (score 4):

Since your input is space delimited you can get away with reading the input with the `>>` operator of the file stream.

```
std::ifstream fin("my_file_to_read");
std::string data;
double a, b;
fin >> data >> a >> b;
```

The above will take

```
65-82 0.015 0.655
```

from the file and input `65-82` into `data` and then stop at the space.  Then `0.015` gets added to `a` and then stops at the space and then `0.655` gets added to `b`.

Since your input starts with a number if you want to make sure that you have 3 values per line then you would need to read in the whole line from the file using [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).  Then you can load that line into a [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) and check if the extraction succedes.

```
std::ifstream fin("my_file_to_read");
std::string data, line;
double a, b;
std::getline(fin, line);
std::stringstream ss(line);
if (!(ss >> data >> a >> b))
{
    //error handling code here
}
```

Comment: OP also wants to be sure that all three values are read it seems from the `int res` in the question and a comment below.

Comment: @RyanHaining something like `if ( fin>>data ) ++res; if (fin>>a) res++;...`?

Comment: @RyanHaining I didn't see that.  I added a way that should handle it well.

Comment: @SergeyA I got that fixed.

Comment: @FerdinandoRandisi Did you `#include <sstream>`?

Comment: I had forgotten about that, that' s why I deleted my previous comment. Thanks. Looking into it now.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ you would typically do something like:

```
std::istringstream stream(line);
std::string temp_string;
double temp_kb, temp_kt;
if (!(stream >> temp_string >> temp_kb >> temp_kt)) {
    // unable to read all values. handle error here
}
```

You cannot write to a string object like that. If you're really bent on using `sscanf()`, you'll need to use a `char[]` array instead and potentially convert that to a `string` afterward.

Comment: That would work, but I do need to store the number of properly read values as well (that is, i need to update the res variable). Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I added some code to perform error handling. If you need to know exactly which value failed to read, you can also do something like `if(!(stream >> temp_string)) { ... } else if (!(stream >> temp_kb)) ...`.

Comment: It is working fine for me. See https://goo.gl/UddbHe for example of it compiling. Did you make sure to `#include <sstream>`?

Comment: I had forgotten about that, that' s why I deleted my previous comment. Thanks. Looking into it now.